# Using jsp to detect the value of a html select menu

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I am new to a Java environment and JSP.  My question is, is is possible to detect the value of a select dropdown option and create a small if statement depending on this value?

For example:

```
<select id="my_select">
    <option value="-1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="0">Option 2</option>
</select>

<c:if test="${id eq -1}">
    Show this
</c:if>

<c:if test="${id gt -1}>
    Show this
</c:if>
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: It maybe possible depending on what you're asking.  When do you expect to see 'Show this'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to first realize the lifecycle of the JSP. The output is formed on the server and sent to the client. Then the client performs some actions and possibly submits a form back to the server.

In your case you have two options:

- use javascript
- submit the form holding the dropdown, and depending on `${param.id}` show one or the other

Comment: Ok great thanks for the info Bozho!  However, that seems like a really big limitation of Java and JSP...in PHP it can be done very easily..ho hum..  Thanks anyway!

Comment: In PHP it is fundamentally really not different from JSP. Both just allows you to generate HTML/CSS/JS (and whatever the client side needs) programmatically. So you're either misunderstanding the answer of Bozho or the core fundamenals of a "server-side web programming language".